UV Map Region Scaling - "Disco Ball" Problem
I am UV unwrapping a set of squares, each separated by a small margin between them in a tessellation (consider the individual mirrors on a disco ball). I want to be able to do accurate AO and material bakes on the margin regions between the squares, so I want those regions to be "thicker" in the UV map.
How do I make the margin between the squares "thicker" in the UV Map, while retaining the same total area?
Starting UV Map:

With the interior squares scaled down by individual origins:

Scaling the "margin" between individual squares up by individual origins does not work as I intend:

A drawing of what I am hoping to achieve:

Thanks!

I'm a little confused... I am assuming that the grey squares are your texture and that you wish each of your unwrapped squares to fit, individually, into each of those squares?  Can we see the model please?

Thanks for the reply! unfortunately I can't send the model, but hopefully I can provide a bit more context.
Another example to describe the model in this region would be the tiles + grout in your bathroom and kitchen. While the tiles are close to being tessellated perfectly, there is a thin line of grout between each tile.
In the model, I want to keep those "grout lines" very thin, but in the UV unwrap I want to shrink the "tiles" by their own origins, and fill the resulting empty UV grid space by making the "grout lines" thicker.
